# How can I set height of chrome extension to browser window height?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I found out that Chrome extension popups have a maximum height of 600px and maximum width of 800px.

My requirement is to make the popup height equal to screen height.

I can see there isn't a simple way to do it but I stumbled upon the Bloomberg extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bloomberg/llgiblikeclfoebojkplbcmnicgcabhg). This somehow fixes the popup height to exactly what I want.

I am new to extension development. How does this Bloomberd extension manage to resize popup to full-screen.

Answer (score 4):

As you found, 600px height and 800px width - are the maximums for a popup size. (see ref in [sources](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/extensions/extension_popup.cc?rcl=084514a32ae45d693e7068b4b63bafcc0aa85b63&l=36))

According mentioned Bloomberg case – it is implemented via injecting code in the current tab using [content-scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).